# Does windows XP SP2 include .net framework by default?

Tags: .net, windows-xp

I am not sure if Windows XP SP2 comes with .net framework 2.0 or not, I tried to search for this but I couldn't find a final word.
So if anyone knows whether a clean install of Windows XP SP2 installs .net framework 2.0+ or not it will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it doesn't contain it. I hope 3.5 is delivered with Windows 7 though. Any Words on that?!

Here is an actual overview which Windows Version included a .Net Version

[.Net Versions (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#History)

Comment: The beta and RC had 3.5 SP1 preinstalled, and as far as i know, it'll stay that way. A pity they couldn't include 4.0.

Answer (score 8):

Nope, it doesn't. The only version of Windows to start including the .Net framework was Vista (and that started with .Net 3.0).

Comment: Windows XP Media Center Edition and Tablet Editions carried .NET 1.0, more here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os.aspx