# .NET Framework Versions

Tags: .net, frameworks

I'm trying to find out which versions of the .NET Framework come installed by default with each operating system. But a few Google searches reveal just a bunch of crap, with no real answers.

Does anybody know any sites that have this information? Preferably coming from Microsoft.

Thank you :)

Comment: Hope this can help.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- **.NET 1.1** is included with **Windows Server 2003**.
- **.NET 2.0** is included with **Windows Server 2003 R2**, but not installed by default.
- **.NET 3.0** is included with **Windows Vista** and **Windows Server 2008**.
- **.NET 3.5** is included with **Windows 7** and **Windows Server 2008 R2**.

**Edit:** Contrary to popular belief, Windows XP SP2 *does not* include the .NET Framework at all, as far as I'm aware. See the following links:

- [Does windows XP SP2 include .net framework by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229622/does-windows-xp-sp2-include-net-framework-by-default)
- [Windows Update keeps reporting that Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2 Update is not installed](http://forums.asp.net/t/1547668.aspx)
- [What version of the .NET framework is installed on Windows XP, Vista, and 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438937/what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-installed-on-windows-xp-vista-and-7)
- [what .NET FRAMEWORK for XP SP2](http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-xp/what-net-framework-for-xp-sp2/168367.html)
- [Is Windows XP SP2 required for .NET Framework 2.0?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2006/01/16/513018.aspx)
- [.NET Framework 2.0 (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#.NET_Framework_2.0)
- [Windows XP Service Pack 2 (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_xp#Service_Pack_2)

Comment: Does XP SP2 have a .NET framework on it? if it does add it to your list.

Comment: Thank you. When I bought a new computer with Windows XP Home Edition years ago when it first came out, it had .NET Framework on it. But back then I didn't know what the hell it was :P

Answer (score -1):

Note that Operation systems prior Windows Vista won't have any .NET Framework installed at all.

Comment: .NET 1.1 or 2.0 is included with XP SP2 (the full service pack). Any new install of XP SP2 or later will contain some form of .NET.

Comment: But you cannot guarantee that some service pack is installed, therefore you cannot know if .net is really installed if you only know the OS.