# How to create a MFC Application to run setup.exe(msi installer)?

Tags: mfc, installation

I have java application (.jar files) and created a batch file to execute the application.
Also, I created a Setup project using Visual Studio 2005 (Setup.exe, .msi).

However, it requires JRE to run. I have downloaded the jre installer (exe file) then would like to bundle it by creating a simple MFC application that calls the two installer (jre installer & Setup.exe).

Here's the list of MFC application functionality that want to create:

1) Upon execution (double click) of the MFC application, want to check if the JRE & my Java application are already installed.

2) If the JRE was found installed, get the installation path, display it to MFC's textbox then disable the textbox and JRE install button. Same with my Java application if found installed.

3) Upon clicking the install button (either JRE or my application), would like to execute the installer.

Any guidance on the right direction is appreciated.

**EDIT:** target OS Windows XP up

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a JRE prerequisite for your installer? Perhaps this will help: [Adding Custom prerequsites to visual studio setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project)

This way you don't need an application which launches installers.

Comment: It was a great idea but as far as I know by adding custom prerequisites to setup project requires .net framework. Which is not default in Windows XP (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229622/does-windows-xp-sp2-include-net-framework-by-default)

Comment: I don't think it does. The Visual Studio bootstrapper doesn't have any software requirements.